# How do I find multiple matches with one regular expression?

Tags: php, regex

I've got the following string:

```
response: id="1" message="whatever" attribute="none" world="hello"
```

The order of the attributes is random. There might be any number of other attributes.

Is there a way to get the id, message and world attribute in one regular expression instead of applying the following three one after another?

```
/ message="(.*?)"/
/ world="(.*?)"/
/ id="(.*?)"/
```

Comment: Yes there is. But the right way is to not use regex for XML and use an actual parser.

Comment: @Jakub Hampl if the string is just the single XML tag, it's certainly regular, so no need for a parser. But in general, I'd agree. It's the better tool, and makes it easier to change in the future, if/when it needs to do "more"

Comment: @Jakug: I know, you're right. I changed the sample, so that argument is resolved. :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can achieve this by using three positive lookahead assertions with `.*` at the front of them:

```
<?php
$re = '/(?=.* message="(.*?)")(?=.* world="(.*?)")(?=.* id="(.*?)")/';

$string = '<response id="1" message="whatever" attribute="none" world="hello" />';

preg_match($re, $string, $matches);
var_dump($matches);
```

Output:

```
array(4) {
  [0]=>
  string(0) ""
  [1]=>
  string(8) "whatever"
  [2]=>
  string(5) "hello"
  [3]=>
  string(1) "1"
}
```

Of course, this pattern will fail if any of those 3 parameters are missing (which might be helpful to you too...).  If you want them to be optional, you can further wrap the inside of the lookahead into a non-capture group and make it optional `(?:....)?` (this example makes the "world" parameter optional)

```
/(?=.* message="(.*?)")(?=(?:.* world="(.*?)")?)(?=.* id="(.*?)")/
```

Comment: Thank you, perfect. I didn't knew about lookaheads and will read up on them.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not a regex guy, so this might be wrong. If it is, don't downvote =) just let me know and I'll delete it! :-D

Could you or the phrases together and match that?

`/ (message|world|id)="(.*?)"/`

Comment: No, this will match only the first attribute it finds and not result in three matches.

Comment: that's a meaningless. you meant `()` and not `[]`. but it wouldn't be possible which attribute value was referring to.

Comment: This will only match the first property.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using [`preg_match`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match.php), then there's an optional third argument which will store all the regular expression *groups* (anything inside parentheses, basically) as well as the full match.

So use the whole thing as one regular expression and then the 2nd, 3rd, and 4th elements will be the `message`, `world`, and `id` respectively (the 1st will be the whole string that matched.

Comment: I know about preg_match() and the matching array, but I'm looking for the right regular expression.

Answer (score 0):

The below is the best one I can come up with. It should capture the actual attributes matched at each point, their values and also allow anything other inbetween. It's not strictly correct though, and you would do well to use a "real" parser.

```
/((message|attribute|world)="([^"]*)").*?((message|attribute|world)="([^"]*)").*?((?:message|attribute|world)="([^"]*)")/
```